# perforce Tagging and labelling files

Tags: perforce

I have to preserve the state of a devel-branch till `revision--123456`.

For that, I have used `p4 label` and `p4 tag` commands to label and tag all the files in the branch. I did this in order to preserve the current state of devel-branch which at the moment is `'Stable'` and allow the developers to continue working further. In case if anyone needed the stable-state of devel branch then he/she can get from `Get Revision` option in p4 client from the label.

I did it using command menu by giving following cmds:

```
p4 label -d CW32_MILESTONE
p4 tag -l CW32_MILESTONE //depot/dev/...@123456
    2669 files added
```

But now when I view the label through p4 client, it's not displaying the revision no. under "Revision" textarea. If I try to explicitly add the revision no. in the textarea then it is showing me following msg:

```
The Revision field can only be added to empty labels.
```

I then created another label using p4 client and specified the `Revision#: 123456`. Now it is showing me the specified revision no. whenever I opened the label, however, the files are not tagged.

I wonder what could be a better approach to keep and maintain the devel-branch upto rev.123456?

Answer (score 2):

The label you are creating with the 'p4 tag' command doesn't record the fact that it's sync'd to changelist 123456. Rather, it is recording:

```
//depot/file/a#3
//depot/file/b#2
//depot/file/c#7
```

and so forth, where those particular revisions (#3, #2, #7) are the revisions that were the head revisions at changelist 123456.

Instead, you could make what's called an "automatic label", by specifying revision 123456 in the "Revision" field of the label spec (using 'p4 label', not 'p4 client'). See: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/label.html#1040665

When you do this, it is true that "the files are not tagged", in the sense that the server doesn't compile a giant list of the precise file revision numbers. However, the net effect is the same, as you can use your development label for the same purposes: you can sync to that label, you can diff files between that label and other labels, etc.

Basically, an "automatic label" is like saving a query and re-executing the query whenever you reference it ("p4 files //depot/dev/...@123456"), while a traditional "tag label" is more like saving the **results** of that query in your label table.

Both techniques are effective, but before giving you more detailed guidance about one versus the other we'd need to know more about what you're trying to achieve, as given what you've said so far, both techniques are fine.